# Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in includes/src/__default.php on line 20256

Tags: magento, php

Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in includes/src/__default.php on line 20256
this is the error from default.php
        $modules = $this->getNode('modules')->children();
under
public function loadModulesConfiguration($fileName, $mergeToObject = null, $mergeModel=null)

I tried to do cache refresh but it went error. I can't go to admin and our server is down.
I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1
Can somebody help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

disable compilation from `system > tools > compilation` or recompile

Answer (score 0):

If you don't disable compile since backend of magento i think you can see the content of include/config.php and you can show two lines into the archive. You can comment it's to disable compilation